# php getimagesize stopped working

Tags: php, getimagesize

My script has been working fine until now; I was able to upload images files without any issues, but not recently. This is how I am troubleshooting the problem:

Check if the file is uploaded or not.

```
if ($_FILES['foto']["error"] > 0){
    echo "Upload of photo image file failed (".$_FILES["foto"]["error"].").";
}
```

No error is returned, hence upload was successful.

Next, I tried to echo out `$_FILES['foto']['tmp_name']`, this too returns the path.

Next, I checked if the function exists: function_exists('getimagesize'); this returns true

Next, I confirm the value of allow_url_fopen = On in php.ini

Finally, this line `var_dump(getimagesize($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name']));` returns bool(false)

What is happening here and why is getimagesize function failing. I tried with different image types.

Comment: Is `error_reporting` enabled? Try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` before you call `getimagesize`.

Answer (score 0):

What if you move the image to a non-temp directory first and then execute `getimagesize`, eg:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'], '/my/dir/' . $_FILES['foto']['name']);
var_dump(getimagesize('/my/dir/' . $_FILES['foto']['name']));
```

Comment: I moved to the file to a known location and recalled var_dump(getimagesize($filename])); it returns bool(false). I checked for the physical file, it is 0 KB. Looks like file is not getting uploaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very strange issue; when I repeated the process using Chrome browser, there was NO ERROR at all. This problem occurs only with the most recent version of Microsoft's internet explorer 11. Apparently, the browser has some issues with uploading the user submitted content.